# Why does W3 Total Cache serve cached pages to logged in users (Wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, php, cache, header-footer, caching

- I'm using a contribution shortcode in a Wordpress page. I need the HTML/XML request to never load from cache for both logged-in and anonymous users.
- In W3 Total Cache, I have the "Don't cache pages for logged in users" checked and the page is excluded from caching in the "Never cache the following pages:" field.
- In spite of this config, once the page has been loaded as a logged in user, all subsequent loads from back/forward browser buttons are from disk cache.

I've tried a combination of configs and various Wordpress header PHP commands, all to no avail.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with CiviCRM? Is it only civicrm pages?

Comment: @AlanDixon, it's not limited to civicrm pages, but nearly all civicrm pages when embedded and loaded from cache will not function correctly.

Comment: When you assert "all subsequent loads from back/forward browser buttons are from disk cache" - are you saying this based on your browser experience, or do you have evidence from the server itself? i.e. are you sure it's not just your web browser caching things? Or does your server have another level of caching (e.g. forward proxy)? If it's not actually limited to CiviCRM, then I doubt this is a civicrm issue, and a wordpress forum would be a better place to find a solution.

Comment: @AlanDixon Fair enough, I'll try a different forum.